# Adding with NULL in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net

i'm planning to add sql values.

```
 Dim cmdStringc23 As String = " Update [Associate_wise_chart] 
        set [Hours]= (select SUM(tat) from [Dashboard].[dbo].[Dashboard] 
        where [assignee] like '%Santosh%') + (select SUM(tat) 
        from [Dashboard].[dbo].[requests] 
        where [assignee] like '%Santosh%') "
```

So consider, 
value from dashboard table is **10**
value from requests table is **NULL**.

So I'm getting answer as 10+NULL = **NULL**.
I have set tat as NULL. My requirement , i have to display answer as **10** and not as **NULL**

Could any one have a look ?

Comment: 10 plus unknown is unknown!

Comment: Do something like `set ColX = coalesce(nullable-select, ColX)`.

Comment: ok, can you help , how to define **TAT** column as null or not null.
i should display the value irrespective of NULL.

Comment: If you set Tat column to NOT NULL you'll get an error instead... (A (sub)select with SUM returns NULL if no rows found.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ISNULL function from SQL ...

```
Update [Associate_wise_chart] 
  set [Hours]= ISNULL((select SUM(tat) from [Dashboard].[dbo].[Dashboard] 
 where [assignee] like '%Santosh%'), 0) + ISNULL((select SUM(tat) 
from [Dashboard].[dbo].[requests]
 where [assignee] like '%Santosh%'), 0) "
```

That will get you ISNULL(10, 0) + ISNULL(NULL, 0) = 10 + 0 = 10

Comment: Actyally, ISNULL is not (ANSI) SQL, it's a product specific function.

Comment: Absolutely, and `COALESCE()`  is the ANSI SQL function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

NULL is a synonym for "unknown". Ten plus unknown is unknown. The unknown can be 0, -1, 42, or even 6E23+π/2. But it's still unknown.

This is why you get NULL.

Instead, check for NULLs, and only add the other value, if it is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

set NOTNULL while creating the table

Comment: Wont help. A (sub)select with SUM returns NULL if no rows found.

Answer (score 0):

fast and easy just convert **tat** column into ***Not Null*** and have 0 in place of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cmdStringc23 As String = " Update [Associate_wise_chart] 
    set [Hours]= (select isnull(sum(tat), 0) from [Dashboard].[dbo].[Dashboard] 
    where [assignee] like '%Santosh%') + (select isnull(sum(tat), 0) 
    from [Dashboard].[dbo].[requests] 
    where [assignee] like '%Santosh%') "
```

Use isnull

Answer (score 0):

Update [Dashboard].[dbo].[Associate_wise_chart] 
set [Hours]= ISNULL ( (select SUM(tat) from [Dashboard].[dbo].[Dashboard] where [assignee] like '%Santosh%'),0) + ISNULL((select SUM(tat)  from [Dashboard].[dbo].Unbuilds where [assignee] like '%Santosh%'),0)  where [Name]='Santhosh'

ISNULL is working. Thank you Everyone.